# Most efficient way in groovy to replace many tokens

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, closures

I have *n* random tokens in a string and i want to use closures to replace each of this values with a return value from a method.

e.g.

> String theString = "Hi, this is \$randomEmail and this is a rand
>   string: \$randomString and this is  a random \$randomTelephoneNumber"

Then what i would like to do is call each applicable method based on the roke to replace that string with an actual value - e.g. for the email address token ($randomEmail) then I want to call the following method;

```
String randomEmailAddress() {
        return new StringBuilder(RandomStringUtils.random(6)).append("@").append(RandomStringUtils.random(6)).append(".com").toString();
    }
```

Was hoping to use closures the string replace function but a little stuck on the next steps..

```
 Map<String,Closure> randomStrings = [randomEmail:{randomEmailAddress()},randomUserName:{randomString(8),randomTelephoneNumber:{randPhoneNumber()}}]
```

Then call the replace function on the string and have each token in turn be replaced with the correct random value.

Note: that there are many base string that I need to manipulate (the example only shows one of them) and I may or may not have all the values present in the file that are in the map (model) at any one time.

i know i can do this with an if statement but defeats the purpose of learning closures:-).

thanks in advance,

Ian.

Comment: I assume the String cannot be changed?  ie:  `def theString = "Hi, this is ${randomEmail()} and this is a rand string: ${randomString()} and this is a random ${randomTelephoneNumber()}"` is out of the question?

Comment: No. it is being read from an external file (I inlined it for simplicity) but a smart approach never the less ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Groovy Templates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates):

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

// single quotes are important here, this needs to be a string, not a gstring.
String template = 'Hi, this is $randomEmail and this is a random username: $randomUserName'

Map model = [
    randomEmail: { -> randomEmailAddress() }, 
    randomUserName: { -> randomUserName() }
]

String result = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template)
    .make(model).toString()
```

Comment: I *always* forget `SimpleTemplateEngine`... Much better answer than mine :-D

Comment: In practice, I do as well! As developers we often outsmart ourselves when trying to do something simple.

Comment: Thanks & very nearly works but I the placeholder change between files so I don't always have every token in the template that is in the model for each of the external files - using StringTemplate I get the following exception and google seems to suggest there is no way around this issue? - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: randomUsername for class: SimpleTemplateScript2

Comment: @Ian The code here uses different capitalisation `randomUserName` vs `randomUsername`. So you have properties that you don't know about beforehand? What are you supposed to do with them?

Comment: @Ian try changing the model to: `Map model = [
    randomEmail: { -> randomEmailAddress() }, 
    randomUserName: { -> randomUserName() }
].withDefault { "\$$it" }`